# How to install modules from CPAN without sudo?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to install modules from CPAN without resorting to `sudo`?

(And without `perlbrew`, please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `cpan` to install modules outside of the system default path. Point it to some place under your home directory and you shouldn't need to call it with `sudo` to install modules.

The `o` command in the `cpan` interactive shell lets you change options for `cpan` and the `makepl_arg` option changes the options that are passed to the `perl Makefile.pl` call that CPAN makes to build the Makefile for the module.

If you wanted to change the install path to `~/lib/perl5` you'd do:

```
mkdir -p ~/lib/perl5
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

And from the CPAN shell:

```
cpan> o conf makepl_arg 'PREFIX=~/lib/perl5'
cpan> install MyModule
```

To use modules installed in this location you'll need to add this path to your `PERL5LIB` environment variable. For bash do:

```
export PER5LIB=~/lib/perl5
```

Or whatever environment variable setting syntax is required by your shell of choice.

There's a nice discussion of customizing CPAN for a single user [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/7512/Set-my-CPAN-install-directory).